# Kotlin variables across activities

Tags: kotlin

I'm having trouble accessing variables from my DataManager.kt to my MainActivity.kt through a Recycler Adapter. On line 30 of Main Activity, I'm getting an unresolved reference and I just can't figure out why. I know the type is incorrect but I should still see the variable from the Main Activity. Code below.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        listItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        listItems.adapter = HotRecyclerAdapter(this, DataManager.users)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    }
}
```

DataManager.kt

```
 class DataManager {
    var users = HashMap<String, User>()
    init{
        initializeUsers()
    }
    private fun initializeUsers() {
        var user = User("user1")
        users.set(user.username, user)

        user = User("user2")
        users.set(user.username, user)

        user = User("user3")
        users.set(user.username, user)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to have an instance of a class to be able to use anything in it. You’re trying to use the name of the class without ever having created an instance of it (by calling it’s constructor) and using that.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an instance variable without ever having created an instance of the class.

If you intend to create an instance of it on `MainActivity` side then you can do something like:

```
// Create Instance
val dataManager = DataManager()
// Access instance varaible
val users = dataManager.users
// Do whatever you want with users
```